# How to send a dropdown list selected value from MVC view to controller's variable ViewData?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC4 with Razor in my application. My controller contains C# coding and view contains cshtml codes. My dropdown list looks like this.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StateName, Model.StateList, "--Please Select--")
```

I want to set the selected values of list to the ViewData component in Controller. Let me know what are all the possibilities to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way ajax call.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      // storing selected value to hidden field
      $("#Selected").val($("#id").val()); 

      $("#id").change(function () { 
        $.ajax({
           url: "~/ ControllerName/ActionMethodName",
           type: 'POST',
           cache: false,
           data: { Selected: $("# Selected").val() },
           success: function (data) {
             //
           }
         });
  });
  )};
</script>
```

Controller:

```
private string ActionMethodName (string Selected)
{
  String value = Selected; 
}
```

Comment: That's fine! Please let me know how to set selected value to ViewData by using javascript only. Expecting a very good answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can store the selected value in hidden field and get the hidden field value at controller like..

.cshtm file

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    // storing selected value to hidden field
    $("#Selected").val($("#id").val());

    $("#id").change(function () {
        // every time dropdown changes the value will be storing in hidden field
        $("#Selected").val($("#id").val());
    });
)};
</script>

@Html.HiddenFor("Selected")
@Html.DropDownList("id", new SelectList(Model.StateList, "--Please Select--"))
```

controller...

you can read hidden field value like..

```
string str = base.Request["Selected"].ToString()
```

Comment: hi sudharshan. Is there any other method to do this without using jQuery.